# Restoring Windows 10 bootloader without access to recovery environment (Windows RE)

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader

My UEFI/GPT installation of Windows 10, 64-bit doesn't boot anymore. It's stuck somewhere in the bootloading process with a blank screen and no error message, I cannot tell at which point exactly.
I suspect that something has been written into the UEFI firmware's NVRAM that prevents Windows from starting up.

Opening the drive on another machine reveals that the partitions, file systems and data are all there and fine. It just doesn't boot anymore.

For possibly [unrelated reasons not relevant to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1251831/unable-to-boot-from-windows-10-usb-drive), I'm unable to boot into the Windows RE environment, but I can boot from Linux USB drives, for example.

Is there a way to repair the BCD and the other bootloader files of Windows 10 without booting into WinRE?

If I understand correctly, commands like [bcdedit affect the NVRAM of the UEFI firmware](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721886(v=ws.10).aspx), so I cannot run those on another machine "against an external drive" that I've mounted, can I?

Any other way to do the same thing, possibly from a live Linux system?

Comment: Those commands have nothing to do with the NVRAM

Comment: @Ramhound I see! I guess I was confusing it with [bcdedit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721886(v=ws.10).aspx). I removed the references to `bootrec` from the question, they were anyway misleading/implying an approach that might not even be relevant. Thanks!

Comment: bcdedit doesn't modify the NVRAM though, the boot configure data exists on a small partition, which points to the volume of where Windows is installed.  NVRAM would be where the certificates for Secure Boot would be stored, which isn't applicable, to your current problem (I am simplifying that statement so don't attempt to read into it).

Comment: @Ramhound I do have access to the EFI system partition and the Windows 10 'recovery' partition when mounting the drive externally to another PC, or when booting into Linux. So how would I go about rewriting/resetting the BCD on that external drive, without WinRE?

Comment: You don't, you need WinRE, might be easier to manually modify the BCD yourself.  If you know the serial of the disk, which is determined when Windows is installed, you can with some adjustments to account for it not being disk 0 manually point to the installation on the external disk.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot find my research I did earlier this week on the process Windows takes to create a unique identifier.  This information is used to boot to the installation, and is contained within the registry, but for whatever reason I cannot find my research (search results) on the subject and since I cannot search my comments I am unlikely to find it the comment I made (for whatever reason I didn't submit an answer).